# Не работает кнопка открытия навигации на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
  width: 1170px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}


/*.........Шапка.............**/

header {
  margin: 12px;
  font: normal 16px sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  color: #229fff;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 90px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-light.bg-ligh {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: #229fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #229fff;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #54a2eb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #54a2eb;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

.call {
  background-color: #f7941d;
  width: 330px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

.num {
  font: normal 14px sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  height: 460px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #229fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md  navbar-light bg-light">
        <a href="https://water.kherson.ua/"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Особистий кабинет</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключатель навигации">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Інформація </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Водоміри</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Розрахунки</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Послуга онлайн</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Профіль</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Вийти</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="call"><img src="https://water.kherson.ua/wp-content/themes/vodokanal/images/support_w1.png"><a href="#" class="num"> Контакт центр:+38(050)811-18-86, 42-22-33</a></div>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопка работает, навигация выводится.
Попробуйте подключить файл стилей Bootstrap c cdn, который я прописал.

Этот:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
  width: 1170px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}


/*.........Шапка.............**/

header {
  margin: 12px;
  font: normal 16px sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  color: #229fff;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 90px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-light.bg-ligh {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: #229fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #229fff;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #54a2eb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #54a2eb;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

.call {
  background-color: #f7941d;
  width: 330px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

.num {
  font: normal 14px sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  height: 460px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #229fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md  navbar-light bg-light">
        <a href="https://water.kherson.ua/"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Особистий кабинет</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключатель навигации">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Інформація </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Водоміри</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Розрахунки</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Послуга онлайн</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Профіль</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Вийти</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="call"><img src="https://water.kherson.ua/wp-content/themes/vodokanal/images/support_w1.png"><a href="#" class="num"> Контакт центр:+38(050)811-18-86, 42-22-33</a></div>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```